# Which name came first, Lucius or Λουκᾶς?

Tags: names, etymology, greek

The etymology of the name [Luke](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luke_(name)) is commonly said to be the Latin name Lucas, itself from [Lucius](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucius), from the praenomen [Lucius](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucius_(praenomen)), from the root [Lux](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/lux) (gen. Lucis).

[A separate etymology says [Λουκᾶς/Λουκανός](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%9B%CE%BF%CF%85%CE%BA%E1%BE%B6%CF%82#Ancient_Greek), derived from a term meaning "man from Lucania". But I'm not particularly concerned with that supposed etymology in this question]

Elsewhere (reading about [Leucism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leucism) in biology *([white stag](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_stag))*) I came across the Geek word [λευκός](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BB%CE%B5%CF%85%CE%BA%CF%8C%CF%82)([HGL](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0057:entry=leuko/s2)) and wondered if that was not a more suitable or a cognate etymology, and found the Greek name [Loukâs ‎(Λουκᾶς)](https://m.name-doctor.com/loukas/) said to be derived from it.

Both Lux and Leukos have the same Proto-IndoEuropean etymology of [*leuk-](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/lewk-), meaning "bright", "to shine", "to see".

In De Praenominibus (Concerning Praenomina), Julius Paris asserts that Lucius is derived from lux, light, and that the name was originally given to children who were born at dawn.

> Can anyone discover or deduct from  historical records what came first: the Latin Lucius from Lux, or the Greek Λουκᾶς from Λευκός? Indeed, perhaps there was a PIE name *Leukos which predates them both! Perhaps an Etruscan or Umbrian origin that someone can find?

**Update**: ... identifiable Umbrian elements in the Etruscan language. ... An Umbrian rather than a non-specific Italic origin can be fully demonstrated only when the form in question shows characteristic Umbrian sound-changes. ... specifically Umbrian are the names vuvzies, vuσia < *Loukios, *Loukiā with Umbrian palatalisation of Italic *k before a front vowel and change of initial *l- to v- (whereas luvce, lauci etc. are borrowed from Latin (cf. class. Lūcius)).

Continues: The complexity of loan  relations may further be illustrated by  lauχme, lauχumes (a personal  name  with  a  derived gentilicium  lauχmsni etc.) and  lucumu  as  a cognomen: are these to  be  linked  with  Lat.  Lucumō, a personal  name but, according to Servius,  originally the Etruscan  word  for ‘king’? Does lauχumneti in  the text  of the linen book (LL IX  f2) belong here  as  ‘in the  regia’ (Meiser 1996, 195)?

An  Italic origin, from the root  *leuk- shine’  has often been  suggested (most recently by Meiser  apud Rix 2005, 564 fn.12, starting from Umbrian *loukumō ‘the most  brilliant’);  Agostiniani (2003)  wonders if there might rather  be  a connection with  Italic  *loukos  ‘sacred grove’, but notes that  in  either  case  the  -χ- is  unexpected.  Can any  safe  conclusion  be  drawn?

Source: [Defining the Etruscans: Language and DNA, John Penney](https://mafiadoc.com/the-etruscan-language-in-its-italic-context-british-museum_5a1028c41723ddd903d75671.html)

Comment: Red alert: the name-doctor site is fanciful/crank, full of erroneous folk etymology. So the   Λουκᾶς from Λευκός path is basically fraudulent. I'm sure the answerers here will reassure you about *that*.

Comment: For the record, the [Greek wikidictionary entry](https://el.wiktionary.org/wiki/Λουκάς) traces the name to Latin, and, of course, the "Greek" name is not attested a century BC in texts or tombstones.  Just because there is a common IE ancestor, *lewk- ,  this hardly establishes a direct path to the name independent of Latin!

Comment: Here is the [LGPN entry](http://clas-lgpn2.classics.ox.ac.uk/cgi-bin/lgpn_search.cgi?name=Λουκᾶς), underscoring how *late* the name is attested in the language.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Why did you never turn that into an answer? You're undoubtedly correct.

Comment: @cmw  OK, I did. My problem is I cannot comment on the Latin, Etruscan, ... , origins... I can only exclude the Greek connection, and underscore my cynicism about popular name sites. The great majority of them are purveyors of misinformation for names such as Catherine (which is likely Coptic), etc.

Answer (score 8):

Red alert: the *name-doctor* site is fanciful/crank, full of erroneous folk etymology. So the Λουκᾶς from Λευκός path is basically fraudulent.  So I can (only) firmly exclude the Greek connection.

For the record, the [Greek wikidictionary entry](https://el.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%9B%CE%BF%CF%85%CE%BA%CE%AC%CF%82) traces the name to Latin.  The  Hellenistic name is not attested  [before the 2nd century BC](http://clas-lgpn2.classics.ox.ac.uk/cgi-bin/lgpn_search.cgi?id=V4-30635&style=) in texts or tombstones; so not *that* long before the eponymous Evangelist.

Just because there is a common IE ancestor, *lewk- , this hardly establishes a direct path to the name independent of Latin!

...of course the unabashedly Roman-inspired name Λουκιανός had entered the Hellenistic  culture/fashion  by the 2nd century AD in Syria, and made famous by the Syrian satirist [Lucian of Samosata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucian).

Here is the [LGPN entry](http://clas-lgpn2.classics.ox.ac.uk/cgi-bin/lgpn_search.cgi?name=%CE%9B%CE%BF%CF%85%CE%BA%E1%BE%B6%CF%82), underscoring how late the name is attested in the Greek language.